# Use a wildcard in CSS selector to style when value is present

Tags: css, wildcard

I am trying to style an element only when that element has a value attribute.

The value attribute is variable (it's a date), but it's the only thing that changes between "no value" and "has value" which I need to style differently.

Is it possible to use a wildcard in the CSS selector ascertain whether the value attribute is present? E.g:

**HTML**

```
<input class="thing" value="variable-something">...</input>
<input class="thing">...</input>
```

**CSS**

```
.thing[value="*"] {
   ...
}
OR
.thing[value=*] {
   ...
}
```

I've tried this solution but use of the `"` makes it look for a specific string. Doing `.thing[value=*]` is invalid and won't compile.

Any advice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<input type="text" value="">
<input type="text">

input[value]{
  background: #ccc;
}
```

Try it yourself https://jsfiddle.net/55rjf0y8/

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code

```css
input[value]{background: red;}
```

```html
<input type="text">
<input type="text" value="">
```